# How can I call setParameter in a request object?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

This is probably due to my misunderstanding and incomplete information of JSP and JSTL. I have a web page where I have input elements such as

```
<input name="elementID" value="${param.elementID}"/>
```

When I am trying to save the form, I check for that elementID and other elements to conform to certain constraints "numeric, less than XXX". I show an error message if they don't. All the parameters are saved and user does not need to type it again after fixing the error.

After saved, when I am redirecting to the same page for the object to be edited,  I am looking a way to set the parameter like `request.setParameter("elementID",..)` Is there a way to do this ? However the only thing I can find is `request.setAttribute`.

Comment: "I am looking a way to set the parameter like request.setParameter("elementID",..)". Why?

Comment: You already found the right method. What's the problem with it? Note, you've a XSS attack hole there. If you're uncertain, read our servlets wiki page for concrete examples: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info

Comment: Thanks. I went with request.setAttribute. Used requestScope.attribute in my <input ... value="${requestScope.attribute}"/> However whenever the validation fails, I restore the attributes from the request parameters to retain the values that the user did input. Once validated, I push the data to my bean. Is there a better design approach ? As for XSS attack hole, current place boss tries to force me write in scriptlets and jdbc. I barely managed to get permission to use jstl. There are bigger holes than this XSS attack hole.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HTTP responses does not support passing parameters.
JSP/Servelets allows you to either use `request.setAttribute` or `session.setAttribute` for that purpose. Both methods are available when processing the page you're redirecting to, So basically, you got it right...

Also, from what you describe, you may want to check client-side validation: don't submit the form until you're validating it using client-side scripting (javascript)

Answer (score 0):

After the servlet processes the form, (ie. saves the user input in the database), have the servlet forward (not redirect, because that would lose the request params) the request to the same jsp which contains the form. So there is no need to set the params since the servlet is just passing back the same request object.

The jsp which contains the form should have inputs similar to this:

```
<form>
...
<input type="text" value="${elementid}"/>
...
</form>
```

The syntax ${varname} is EL. So if the elementid already has a value, it that textfield will contain that value. Alternatively if you have not used EL and/or JSTL, you use scriptlets (but that is highly unadvisable, EL and/or JSTL should be the way):

```
<form>
...
<input type="text" value="<%= request.getParameter("elementid") %>"/>
...
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to include `<%@ page isELIgnored="false"%>` to my jsp to allow code like `${elementid}` to work